# Interesting Probablity Problem: Average Number of Generations With n Different Balls, Where Each Draw Doubles the Other Balls

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

The original question is worded as follows:"You have n people and give each a ball to put into a hopper, which randomly takes one out each time. Whenever someone is picked, their ball gets re-fed into the hopper, and everyone else doubles the amount of balls they have in the hopper.
Provided that they all start with 1 ball inside of the hopper, on average, how long will it take for each person to have an equal amount of balls in the hopper again?"

I have so far solved only the case where there are 2 balls, with the average number of generations being:$\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}8]{2}\, \vartheta(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}))$ or in another form: $\lim_{n \to \infty}{1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k}+1}{\sqrt{2}^{k^{2}+k-2}}}$

How would this problem be solved with a larger number of balls? Is there a closed form solution for the general case?

I'm super curious to see what a general solution looks like. Thanks for your help!

===================================================================

Edit: My proof for N=2 case. (Note: I'm still early in my math career, so I haven't taken any classes on how to write a proof properly, so it might be lacking a bit of rigor. Nonetheless, experimental evidence matches this value to 15 decimal places)

Observation: Although the problem appears to require two indepdent variable, it can be fully expressed with only one variable. Since we start with one of each type of ball (I'll express that as [1,1]), then after some number of turns the number of balls can be expressed as [$2^i$,$2^j$]. The chance to choose ball 1 is $\frac{2^i}{2^i + 2^j}$, and the chance to choose ball 2 is $\frac{2^j}{2^i + 2^j}$. This formula actually stays the same if we double both of them. ($\frac{2^{i+1}}{2^{i+1} + 2^{j+1}})$ = $(\frac{2 \times 2^{i}}{2 \times (2^{i} + 2^{j})})$ = ($\frac{2^{i}}{2^{i} + 2^{j}})$. This is important because it means we can express the relationship always as [1,$2^j$] (all I did is divide by $2^i$). Also, since the 2^ part is always there, its much more useful to start working with [1,j], so I'll start using that from now on.

Observation #2: We finish when j=0 in [1,j]. When we choose the first ball (with a chance of $\frac{1}{1+2^j}$), the other ball gets doubled, so we then have [1,$j+1$]. If we choose the larger ball (with a $\frac{2^j}{2^j+1}$ chance), the smaller ball gets doubled, and we have [2,j]. But since we can always divide both by 2, and end up with an equalivent representation, we can also write this as [1,j-1].

Formula: 
With those observations in mind, we can write a recursive formula for the average number of generations as $f(n) = 1 + \frac{2^n}{2^n+1}f(n-1) + \frac{1}{2^n+1}f(n+1)$ And as an initial condition we know that $f(0)=0$

Based on our intial values, we can start computing some terms:

$f(1)= 1 + \frac{1}{3}f(2)$

$f(2)= f(2)$

$f(2)=1+\frac{4}{5}f(1)+\frac{1}{5}f(3)->5f\left(2\right)-5-4\ -\frac{4}{3}\left(f\left(2\right)\right)=\left(f\left(3\right)\right)$

$f\left(3\right)=\frac{11}{3}f\left(2\right)-9$

And based on this, it seems like a good choice to say that, in general, $f(n)= a(n)f(2)+b(n)$ (I'll show that this works out later)

Also, from here on out, I'll let $c = f(2)$.

Let $f(n)= a(n)c+b(n)$, then by plugging into $f\left(n\right)=1+\frac{2^{n}}{2^{n}+1}f(n-1)+\frac{1}{2^{n}+1}f(n+1)$, we arrive at $$\left(\left(2^{n}+1\right)a\left(n\right)\right)c+\left(\left(2^{n}+1\right)b\left(n\right)\right)=\left(2^{n}a\left(n-1\right)+a\left(n+1\right)\right)c+\left(2^{n}b\left(n-1\right)+b\left(n+1\right)+\left(2^{n}+1\right)\right)$$
This can be split between the part multiplied by c, and the constant part so for the multiplied c part: $\left(2^{n}+1\right)a\left(n\right)=2^{n}a\left(n-1\right)+a\left(n+1\right)$, simplifying, we get $\left(2^{n}\right)\left(a\left(n\right)-a\left(n-1\right)\right)=\left(a\left(n+1\right)-a\left(n\right)\right)$. If we let $Δa\left(n\right)=a\left(n+1\right)-a\left(n\right)$, then $Δa\left(n\right)=\left(2^{n}\right)\left(Δa\left(n-1\right)\right)$  Solving that equation gives $Δa_{n}=2^{\left(\log_{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+\frac{\left(n-1\right)^{2}+\left(n-1\right)}{2}\right)}$, and therefore $$a(n) = \sum_{n=1}^{k-1}2^{\left(\log_{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+\frac{\left(n-1\right)^{2}+\left(n-1\right)}{2}\right)}$$

A similar method is used for solving for $b(n)$. We get $Δb_{n}=\left(2^{n}\right)Δb_{n-1}-\left(2^{n}+1\ \right)$, which gives us that $Δb_{n}=2^{\frac{\left(n^{2}+n-2\right)}{2}}\left(2+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{-\left(2^{k}+1\ \right)}{2^{\frac{\left(k^{2}+k-2\right)}{2}}}\right)\right)$ And $$b(n)=\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}\left(2^{\frac{\left(j^{2}+j-2\right)}{2}}\left(2+\sum_{k=1}^{j}\left(\frac{-\left(2^{k}+1\ \right)}{2^{\frac{\left(k^{2}+k-2\right)}{2}}}\right)\right)\right)$$

With both a(n) and b(n), the problem is almost done. Since we assume that the average number of generations is finite, and therefore $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = 1 + f(n-1) $$. We replace $f(n)$ with $a(n)c+b(n)$, and then simplify. $\lim_{n \to \infty} a\left(n\right)c+b\left(n\right)=1+a\left(n-1\right)c+b\left(n-1\right)$ So $$c=\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{\left(1+b\left(n-1\right)-b\left(n\right)\right)}{\left(a\left(n\right)-a\left(n-1\right)\right)})$$
After a pretty large deal of simplying, at last we get 
$$c=\lim_{n \to \infty}(-3+\frac{3}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k}+1}{\sqrt{2}^{k^{2}+k-2}})$$
But that only gives us the starting configuration [1,4]. To get the configuration, we use that $f(1)=  1 + \frac{1}{3}f(2)$, and that gives $f(1) = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k}+1}{\sqrt{2}^{k^{2}+k-2}}\right)$ Also, since we decided to start with the configuration [1,1], we have to add one (since after one iteration, it always becomes [2,1]=f(1)), so finally $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^{k}+1}{\sqrt{2}^{k^{2}+k-2}}\right)$$

===================================================================

Edit: After working on the problem for a fair bit longer, it does seem like there is at least a solution to the N=3 case in closed form. I'm making progress towards the N=3 case, and I'll update this question if I manage to solve it

Comment: The closed form you got for $n = 2$ can be simplified to $\sqrt[8]{2}\ \vartheta\left(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$

Comment: I've simplified that in the question, thanks for the catch!

Comment: Could you please edit into your question how you got that closed form for $n = 2$?

Comment: Sure! Its a pretty long chain of steps, whats the preferred way to add it? Should I just write a proof below? Or should I rewrite it in overleaf or something, and then add a link? I'm new to using stack exchange, so your advice would be appreciated

Comment: The best way would just be to include it in the question (by editing), rather than use Overleaf or write an answer for it.

Comment: Regarding the question, I am doubtful that there is a closed form for general $n$.